# Pima Club Wheat Expectations

Tags: winter-gardening, desert, food-crops

I'm growing Pima Club wheat from seeds and will plant in the last week of October (central Arizona desert).  What can I expect to see in terms of growth and yield from this wheat?  I'm planning to dedicate maybe 8 sqft at this time as a proof of concept sort of thing.

I've read that this is a great winter crop and requires almost no maintenance.  Is that really true?  What is required to get a reasonably good yield (considering this is a small backyard garden)?

I'm doing this as more of an experiment to see if I can make my garden more productive through the "deep" winter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three questions here:

1. What can I yield can I expect?
2. Is it true that this is a great winter crop with almost no maintenance?
3. What is required to get a reasonably good yield?

Here's what I found on question 1 for White Sonora wheat - a kind of sister wheat to Prima Club:

> This is fairly typical return with wheat, it should be in the range of about 40:1, meaning if you plant 1 oz. your harvest should be around 40 oz.
> [White Sonora Wheat - Perfect Grain for the Home Gardener](https://underwoodgardens.com/white-sonora-wheat-perfect-grain-home-gardener/)

From another source:

> **History**
> Pima Club wheat is one of four varieties used by the Pima Indians in southern Arizona since it was introduced by Father Kino in the sixteenth century into the Sonoran region of Northern Mexico and Southern Arizona that completely altered the food life of the Pima tribes.
>
> Four wheat varieties became the backbone of the Pima or O’odham nation; the White Sonora, the Pima Club, a semi-hard variety called Baart and a black wheat. Pima Club is preferred for making Pinole as it is a round, beardless and soft type of wheat. Pima Club was lost for a time, but was rediscovered in one of the O’odham village and grown out by a few families for Pinole, an ancient drink made from finely ground, toasted wheat or corn.
>
> **Planting Rates**
> 3oz = approx 1500 seeds, enough for a 10 x 10 ft plot, or 100 Sq. ft.
> 6oz = approx 3000 seeds, enough for a 20 x 20 ft plot, or 400 Sq. ft.
> 1lb = approx 8,000 seeds, enough for a 50 x 50 ft plot, or 2,500 Sq. ft.
> [Prima Club Wheat Seeds](https://store.underwoodgardens.com/Pima-Club-Wheat-Triticum-aestivum/productinfo/V1459/)

Keeping in mind that there are several variables - planting rate, water, sun, temperature, etc. - that come into play that might affect your results this will give you a ball park to play in.